# Google oauth2 - g-signin2 not automatically signing in after first sign in for intranet non-FQDN domain

Tags: google-oauth

I have a page using google oauth on an intranet IIS server at: https://intranet/application
The same page is reachable at:
https://intranet.domain.com/application

For some reason, the g-signin2 -  button always displays on page load for the non-FQDN link. The user has to click 'Sign In' and the dialog to select their account pops up every time. The FQDN link automatically signs in after first sign in.

I'd like the normal behavior of: after the first sign in, the user is automatically signed in on subsequent visits unless they sign out. Currently the sign in does work except for this issue.

There are no errors displayed. This is using Chrome.

Code as requested:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
...
<div class="google_sign_on"><div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div></div>
...
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    ...
    profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); 
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: Are both domains authorized as JavaScript origins for your Client ID on the Google Developer Console?